# SAFARI rendering input checkbox with value. How to disable value in checkbox?

Tags: html, checkbox, safari

I have checkbox input line with closed tag:

```
<input  class="rating" type="checkbox" name="ratings[]" value="{{ rating['rating'] }}" />
```

Safari rendering it to by changing closed tag and adding value there:

```
<input  class="rating" type="checkbox" name="ratings[]" value="4">4</input>
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your `class` attribute to set value for your `checkbox`

```
<input  class="rating" type="checkbox" name="ratings[]" />
```

then you can use script tag in order to give value to checkbox.

```
<script>
 var testJava = rating['rating'];
 document.getElementsByClassName("rating").value = testJava;
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. It was my fault. It was rendered when i tried disable some checkboxes (on some conditions) with jquery script. So issue in my jquery. I have solved it by editing my script. But anyway, it is the strange effect which not present on another browsers...